# Table Rates Post Code Wild Cards

Tags: magento2.3, shipping, table-rates

I have Table Rates set up. The special postcodes are not working - they just use the default value.

I know Table rates are working because if I alter the default line below it is used.

I hope it is something to do with the format of my CSV file.

[image: CSV]

Any ideas?

Comment: which version do you want to update the shipping rate? Magento 2 or Magento 1.

Comment: Hi Magento 2.3.2 - I'm using the built in Table rates

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below tutorial, it will help you to configure the shipping table rates method using the postcode.

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/shipping-table-rate.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16955604/table-rates-zip-code-csv-format

Please let me know if you still facing the same issue.